# Getting error in react native : Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

error in new build :

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Error 'D:\projects\react\New folder\new\awesome\android\app\build\outputs\logs\manifest-merger-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)' while writing the merger report file, build can continue but merging activities will not be documented
> 11 actionable tasks: 11 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\projects\react\New folder\new\awesome\android\app\build\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Comment: use `sudo` before the command you used to execute code like `sudo react-native run-android` or `sudo npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

make sure installed HAXM (for intel) or Hypervisor (for amd) on sdk tools
you need a start first `npx react-native start` code in powershell (c:\yourusarname\yourprojectname)
after open new powershell and `npx react-native run-android` (or ios)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add `org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED` to ./android/gradle.properties file in your project

it works like magic